# Why is there an extra "?" displayed after executing C program(to read aand display a txt file)

Tags: c, file-io, terminal

I wrote a C program which reads an existing txt file and outputs the contents inside that file.

The issue I'm having is that it displays a `?` at the end.

For example: if the contents in the file(txt) were `Hello World!`, the terminal displays `Hello World!?`.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * fp;
    char ch;
    char filename[100];
    char filename2[100];

    printf("Enter the file you want to display(without .txt): \n");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    sprintf(filename2, "%s.txt", filename);
    /* opens the file in read mode */
    fp = fopen(filename2, "r");

    /* NULL if last operation was unsuccessful */
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("File opened successfully. \n\n");
    while (ch != EOF)
    {
        /* Read single character from file */
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        /* Print character */
        putchar(ch);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're attempting to print it before checking if it's `EOF`.

Comment: ch should be an int, not a char. Also: it doesn't seem to be initialised.

Comment: Not exact duplicate but related: [c - Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Friend it is working just fine!!

Comment: Every time some process writes `Unable to open file.\n` to stdout, a kitten dies.  `perror(filename2);`

Comment: Don't read the parameter from stdin, and *never* use `"%s"` in a scanf.  It is as bad as `gets()`.  Just do `char *filename = argv[1]; char *filename2 = argv[2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if the reading is successful *before* trying to use what is "read".

Also [`fgetc()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc) returns `int`, so the variable `ch` should be `int`, otherwise it will make it difficult to distinguish between one of valid characters with EOF.

```
    for (;;)
    {
        /* Read single character from file */
        ch = fgetc(fp);

        /* Check if something is actually read */
        if (ch == EOF) break;

        /* Print character */
        putchar(ch);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the file contents to another file, and kill the file .
And try once again.
Some time it happens because of the garbage value.

Otherwise just use this code once the file is read.

```
fflush(stdin);
fflush(stdout);
```

if that didn't work use these in some other appropriate places in the code.
Sometime it happens because of the input and output buffer.